# Finding the density of $X^{-1}$ given the density of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ is a positive random variable with density $f$. I need to prove that the density of $X^{-1}$ is $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)/x^{2}$, and I need to do it in two different ways:

1. First Way: Using the result that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}P[g(X)\leq x ] = f(T(x))|T^{\prime}(x)|$.

In the paragraph preceding it, it says the following:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous and $g$ is increasing, and let $T = g^{-1}$. The distribution function of $g(x)$ is $P[g(X) \leq x] = P[X \leq T(x)] = F(T(x))$. If $T$ is differentiable, this differentiates to $f(T(x))T^{\prime}(x)$, which is therefore the density for $g(X)$. If $g$ is decreasing, on the other hand, then $P[g(X)<x] = P[X > T(x)] = 1-F(T(x))$, and the derivative is equal to $-f(T(x))T^{\prime}(x) = f(T(x))|T^{\prime}(x)|$. In either case, $g(X)$ has density $$ \frac{d}{dx}P[g(X) \leq x] = f(T(x))|T^{\prime}(x)|.$$

Now, I am confused about what $g$ and $T$ are supposed to be. It says that $T = g^{-1}$, and it makes sense from the fact that $\displaystyle f\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)/x^{2} = \frac{1}{x^{2}}\cdot f\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)$ that $T(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, but it also makes sense that $g(X) = \frac{1}{X}$ from the fact that we're looking to find the density of $\frac{1}{X}$ and the result gives us the density of a function of $X$.

Could somebody please clarify this for me? I feel like this should not be nearly as complicated as I'm making it.

2. Second Way: Using a direct argument.

Let $F$ be the distribution function for $X$ so that $F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f$, where $f$ is the density function of $X$. Let $Y:=\frac{1}{X}$. Then, $F_{Y}(t) = P(Y<t) = P \left(\frac{1}{X} < t \right) = P \left(X > \frac{1}{t} \right) = \int_{1/t}^\infty f(x)dx$, so $f_{Y}(t) = f\left(\frac{1}{t} \right) \left | - \frac{1}{t^{2}}\right |$.

Did I do that part correctly? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: For the first question: The inverse function of $g(x)=1/x$ is $T(x)=1/x$. So you have to follow the textbook.

Comment: @kmitov so it is! Thank you. What about for the second part?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Math1000 thank you for letting me know!